# Can't connect Fedora computer to LAN via switch

Tags: switch, fedora, local-area-network

I am trying to network a few computers on a LAN with a switch (no internet necessary). The networking devices I have available are a router, a managed switch, and an unmanaged switch. when I connect devices to the router with ethernet, I can ping/ssh among the devices without further configuration. The router has too few ports for my setup though, so I'm trying to use a switch which does have enough ports. I have managed and unmanaged switches available. In either case, all the machines can connect successfully except one: Macbooks can connects, but a Fedora laptop cannot.

Here are some networking details from the unsuccessful laptop:

```bash
└─> lspci | grep Ethernet
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM (rev 21)

└─> ifconfig -a
enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.210  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether e8:6a:64:63:90:9d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1554512  bytes 118177517 (112.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1522  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9199699  bytes 13901777883 (12.9 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xe9200000-e9220000  

enp11s0u1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:50:b6:b3:a2:94  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 163581  bytes 46482278 (44.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 163581  bytes 46482278 (44.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:e6:4f:80  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.13  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::e460:c4a7:aa27:5ced  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1c:1b:b5:da:e2:83  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5572376  bytes 3628077555 (3.3 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5301580  bytes 3638710195 (3.3 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Make sure all your hosts are configured to the same IP subnet, e.g. 192.168.0.0/24.

Comment: Thanks @Zac67. Is it correct to say that I need to either assign static IPs [in the same subnet] on each machine, or use something with a DHCP server like a wired router or a switch with a router connected?

Comment: Exactly. Hosts in different subnets require a router for communication even if they're connected to the same switch/VLAN. Hosts within a shared subnet don't require or use a router.